# VS2010 Update Nuget package to a specific version, but also update dll References in projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

For example my solution uses Nuget package "foo" with version "1.2.30".
I want to Update "foo" package for all my solution projects to version "1.2.25", for example.
I can't do it through Visual Studio Nuget addon, because if I right click on solution -> Manage packages -> Updates, Nuget won't propose me to update to the version that I want. Nuget will propose only the latest version.

So, I'm using workaround like this:

> 1. Manually change "packages.config" files for all projects that use this package from "1.2.30" to "1.2.25" package version.
> 2. Right click on solution and Restore packages (Nuget will download "foo" v1.2.25).
> 3. After that I need to update References in all projects that use this package, because they still reference "1.2.30".  So I open every
>      project "References", Remove the "foo" dll reference(v1.2.30) and then
>      click Add and add dll reference "foo"(v1.2.25).

**Questions:**

> 1. Nuget VS2010 addon is so awesome, why doesn't it have "update to specific version" option *in Visual Studio 2010*?
> 2. Is there any other easier steps to do what I want ?

Thanks a lot, that's really bugging me.

==========**ANSWER:**==========

You can use Package Manager Console(Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console) in Visual Studio to command Nuget what to do via console. 
It is much more flexible than "Manage Nuget packages".

Examples:
Update package "foo" only for project "MyProject":

> Update-Package -Id foo -Version 1.2.25 -ProjectName MyProject -IncludePrerelease

Update package "foo" for all projects in solution:

> Update-Package -Id foo -Version 1.2.25 -IncludePrerelease

Full help can be found here:

> http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this from the Package Manager Console. The following should update all NUnit NuGet packages to version 2.6.1 which is not the latest version.

```
Update-Package NUnit -version 2.6.1
```